# Android Studio 2.0 Gradle Bug

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I wasn't sure what to name the question so bear with me.

I work on two machines, my PC and my Mac. Currently I have upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 on my PC to get all the new features and it is a mess. I need help.

So what is happening is that when I try to run the app the gradle build fails. It fails with this message :

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2320Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.SF
File1: C:\Users\Andy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.51\6c8c1f61bf27a09f9b1a8abc201523669bba9597\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.51.jar
File2: C:\Users\Andy\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.51\9ab8afcc2842d5ef06eb775a0a2b12783b99aa80\bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.114 secs

Here is a list of my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.hierynomus:sshj:0.15.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Now the odd thing is that if I run the exact same source code on my mac its fine. So what is going on? Is this a bug with v2.0, it seems unlikely though.

If you need any more info let me know!

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Please post the entire Gradle console output, not just those lines.

Comment: OK, you have duplicate files, from two separate Bouncy Castle JARs. Unless they repackaged recently, Bouncy Castle is not recommended for Android apps anyway, due to the fact that Android has a truncated edition of Bouncy Castle inside of it, and you wind up with conflicts. It used to be that you had to use [Spongy Castle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/). I'd focus on that first, as it may clear up this problem as a side effect. Otherwise, figure out an exclusion rule to only wind up with one copy of this file.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the issue but I've never added the Bouncy Castle Jar myself. If I post my dependencies could you see if you know any that may cause this conflict? Otherwise I don't even know where to start to fix this issue

Comment: I see several dependencies in your output, all from the Android Support package. I am fairly confident that none of them are using Bouncy Castle. You might try cleaning your project, as perhaps these are leftovers from some past build. Otherwise, if you have dependencies from things outside of the Android Support package, list them, and perhaps we can track down where the JARs are coming from.

Comment: @CommonsWare edited the post

Comment: `sshj` seems like a likely candidate, off the cuff. Conversely, none of the others do.

Comment: That was it... thanks man, if you want to make an answer I will accept yours.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not quite sure how to phrase an answer here... :-) You might want to try answering it yourself, as you know your situation (and your resolution to the `com.hierynomus:sshj` wanting Bouncy Castle) better.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey so with some help I figued out that com.hierynomous:sshj was also wanting Bouncy Castle and therefor conflicting with the caked in Android one.

Hope this helps someone in the future.